# Mootools Fading all column table?

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

First thanks to the people have helped me answering most of my questions. I am new at mootools and really need some help with specific things like chaining functions, effects, etc.

I would like to fade in an entire column on a table, but the thing is I populate the table and its rows on page load, and hide that columns I dont want to show(statically are 5 columns). but I have the functionality to remove an entire column and then has to appears a new one at the end.  The hidden column has a class with display none.
I am ussing moootools to remove selected column and I want with mootools to appears first on show column with an effect, like fade in.

Here are my functions:

```
$$('.RemoveColumn').each(function (el) {
    el.addEvent('click', function (e)
    {
        DeleteCurrentColumn(el.get('id'));
        ShowNextColumn();
    })
})

function DeleteCurrentColumn(id) {
    var identifier = '.columnclass' + id;
    $$(identifier).each(function (el) {
        el.dispose();
    })
}

function ShowNextColumn() {
    var firstNoDisplay = $$('.noDisplay')[0]; // Select first item with nodisplay class
    var MyId = firstNoDisplay.get('id');
    if ((firstNoDisplay != null) && (MyId)) {
        var identifier = '.columnclass-' + MyId;
        $$(identifier).each(function (el) {
            if (el.hasClass('noDisplay'))
                el.removeClass('noDisplay');
        })
    }
}
```

I think I have to set the opacity of all the elements of the columns at 0 and the fade in...but cant figure it out how :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So we can help you better: __1:__ - why do you use sometimes `.columnclass-` (with `-` in the end) and other times just `.columnclass` ? __2:__ - Please post your HTML or update this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XMaXj/

Comment: It is an Xsl with foreach, I contruct the table by rows.

Comment: Hi I already updated the fiddle at jsfiddle.net/XMaXj thanks!!!

Comment: you could do `$('.foo').dispose()` without the each. but dispose does not remove element. it just detached from the DOM. you may want to use .destroy instead or you may get leaks and force your GC to do extra work

Comment: I tried with the $$(identifier).distroy(); and any success :(

Comment: You have a typo in your comment, destroy should be with e not i

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
function ShowNextColumn() {
    var firstNoDisplay = document.getElement('.nodisplay'); // Select first item with nodisplay class
    var MyId = firstNoDisplay.get('data-id');
    if ((firstNoDisplay != null) && (MyId)) {
        var identifier = '.columnclass' + MyId;
        $$(identifier).each(function (el) {
            if (el.hasClass('nodisplay')) el.fade('in');
        })
    }
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5bnJ2/)

What I changed:

- use `.fade('in')` for fading io and use `opacity: 0;` instead of `display: none;`
- use `document.getElement('.nodisplay');` instead of `$$('.noDisplay')[0];` and note the class should be all smallcase
- removed the `-` in the classname here: `'.columnclass-' + MyId;`

Comment: Hi Sergio, I was doing your example! Thanks! But I dont know what is happening but when I remove a column at the middle or before the last visible one, the the colum appears at the next position of the remove column and it has to appears at the end all columns. Thank!

Comment: @user2528557, can you explain the same comment using the column numbers on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/5bnJ2/1

Comment: Hi there I finally get a solution, I just had to remove the noDisplay class, so when I seek for the first one, the one was showed wont, if you know what I mean.